# Store in LocalStore an element added by jquery via append()

Tags: jquery, local-storage, storage

I would like to store in LocalStore an element added by jquery via `append()`. I've used [Storage.js](https://github.com/ekdevdes/storage.js) to store datas but after refreshing, item aren't stored in LocalStore. What is that I have forgot ?

HTML

```
<a href="#f" id="i_">→1</a><br>
<a href="#f" id="i_">→2</a><br>
<a href="#f" id="i_">→3</a>

<input id="add" type="button" value="Add">
```

JS

```
$("#add").bind("click", function () {
 var id = $(this).prev().attr('data-key');
 var number = id.substring(6, 8);
 $("#add").before('<br><a href="#f" id="i_" data-orig-text="→' + number + '" data-key="' + id + '" contenteditable class>→' + number + '</a>');
});

$('a').storage({storageKey:'Links'});
```

A demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/DgV78/20/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Storage.js, it would be better using HTML5 LocalStorage, here is the [full documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). It's something like below:

To save a data into the local storage:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Code for localStorage/sessionStorage.
    var saved_html = "";
    $("a").each(function(){
       saved_html += $(this).html();
    });
    localStorage.setItem("saved_html", saved_html);
} else {
    // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
}
```

To get the data:

```
$("body").html(localStorage.getItem("saved_html"));
```

Note: I cannot try it out on your fiddle because its missing the `data-key`..